# Difference between output of `ls -sh` and `ls -lsh`

Tags: command-line, ls

```
$ ls -lsh file.qcow2
204K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 193K Jul 19 15:18 file.qcow2`

$ ls -sh file.qcow2                                                                                           204K file.qcow2`
```

What is the significance of 193K in the output of `ls -lsh <file>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the man pages when in doubt.

```
man ls
```

shows the following:

```
   -l     use a long listing format
   -s, --size
          print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
   -h, --human-readable
          with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Without the `-l` you do not see all the permissions, owner, size and date information of the file.

The `-s` means to print the `allocated` size of the file.  The `193K` you are seeing is the actual size.  The `204K` is the allocated size as the drive is divided up into `4K` clusters.  `204K / 4 = 51` as that means the file takes 51 clusters.

Comment: Interesting to observe that the _allocated size_ isn't `196K` (=49*4) because a 193K file would fit into 49 blocks 4K each. – But that would be another question...